# Android com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView animateCamera does not work the first time

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have an activity with a mapview.
I have some code to animate the camera to include all markers in the mapview.
The first two times I call my animate camera code after starting it's activity, it does not work.
From the third time on, it works normally.
Any explanation for this?

Here is my relevant code:

```
            if (filteredList.size() > 0)
            {
                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                for (Marker marker : markers)
                {
                    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
                }
                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                int padding = 50; // offset from edges of the
                                    // map in pixels
                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                map.animateCamera(cu);
            }
```

This code gets called once after loading the activity and getting data from a webservice (and does NOT work).
It gets called a second time when the user presses a button (and still does NOT work).
It gets called more times again responding to a button press from the user, and works normally from then on.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check your log cat for any error messages, but it looks your map is not yet initialized at the moment of first two calls

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that can't be the problem as he said after pressing a button it still *doesn't work*.

Comment: It can. GMaps is initialized asynchronously

Comment: Sure if he's spamming the button before the map loaded..

Comment: I think the best way for you to test if you are just pressing the button before map is initialized, is to wait a bit and see if you can NOT get the button to work the first time.

Comment: It could also be unrelated to maps -- if `filteredList` does not get initialized properly for whatever reason until the after the first button click, the map will not update.  I would look at your logic for populating `filteredList`, too.

Comment: To asnwer your doubts, I don't spam the button right away. No matter how much I wait, it still does not work.

Comment: And filteredList is initialized, since I debugged and saw it was good, and also all the markers, which are also created from "filteredList", are being shown on the map

Comment: I will look at LogCat and check if I see something strange...

Comment: LogCat was revealing:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.

Comment: So the question now becomes... how do I get the map's layout event, so I can make sure try to animate the camera again after layout has occurred?

Answer (score 0):

The first button press set the map's visibility to Visible from Gone, so it turns out it actually wan't yet initialized.
Credit to Marcin Orlowski.
I fixed it by adding this:
mapView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener()
        {

```
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
        {
            if (firstMapLayout)
            {
                firstMapLayout = false;
                rebuildMap();
            }
        }
    });
```

Where "rebuildMap()" is the function that contains the camera animation code.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully use the `onMapLoadedCallback` like this:

```
        mapView.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            mapLoaded = true;

            // show location on map or execute any code that you need 
            // after the map loading
        }
    });
```